# Unexpected NA values in ANOVA, GLM summary, and pairwise differences

Tags: r, na, glm, anova

Running the following GLMs:

```
MM11\<-glm(CR \~ Species + Season + Habitat, data=ds1)
MM12\<-glm(CR \~ Species \* Season + Habitat, data=ds1)
MM13\<-glm(CR \~ Species + Season \* Habitat, data=ds1)
MM14\<-glm(CR \~ Species \* Habitat + Season, data=ds1)
MM15\<-glm(CR \~ Species \* Habitat \* Season, data=ds1)
```

Trying to find the best model with ANOVA

```
anova(MM11, MM12, MM13, MM14, MM15, test="Chisq")
```

Gives me the following error:
Error in if (dispersion == 1) Inf else min(resdf) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
So, I run the following:

```
AIC(MM11, MM12, MM13, MM14, MM15)
```

It shows that MM15 has the lowest scores, so I run an ANOVA just for MM15

```
Anova(MM15) # Full of NAs
```

The result is full of NA values. Similarly, the summary of MM15 is also riddled with NAs. Also, the same with pairwise differences using the [estimated marginal means](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) function. This is not the case for any of the other models.

Any help to make sense of this and fix it is appreciated.
Thank you.

What I have is the following:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: CR
                       LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
Species                     NaN  3        NaN
Habitat                     NaN  2        NaN
Season                      NaN  1        NaN
Species:Habitat             NaN  4        NaN
Species:Season              NaN  3        NaN
Habitat:Season              NaN  1        NaN
Species:Habitat:Season      NaN  1        NaN
```

What I'm expecting is something like this:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: CR
                         LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Species                    45.423  3  7.522e-10 ***
Habitat                     6.434  2    0.04007 *  
Season                      2.275  1    0.13145    
Species:Habitat            26.451  5  7.294e-05 ***
Species:Season             2.5307  3   0.469771
Habitat:Season            11.0975  2   0.003892 **
Species:Habitat:Season     1.4956  1   0.23845
```

```
dput(ds1)
```

Gives the following output:

structure(list(Season = c("Southwest monsoon", "Southwest monsoon",
"Southwest monsoon", "Southwest monsoon", "Southwest monsoon",
"Southwest monsoon", "Southwest monsoon", "Southwest monsoon",
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter",
"Winter", "Winter"), Habitat = c("Farmland", "Farmland", "Savannah",
"Savannah", "Savannah", "Savannah", "Scrubland", "Scrubland",
"Farmland", "Savannah", "Savannah", "Savannah", "Savannah", "Scrubland",
"Scrubland", "Scrubland", "Scrubland"), Species = structure(c(2L,
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "5"), class = "factor"), Capture = c(3,
1, 4, 15, 3, 1, 12, 7, 8, 1, 22, 3, 1, 1, 19, 9, 2), Trap = c(590L,
590L, 1761L, 1761L, 1761L, 1761L, 1197L, 1197L, 598L, 1703L,
1703L, 1703L, 1703L, 1134L, 1134L, 1134L, 1134L), CR = c(0.00508474576271186,
0.00169491525423729, 0.00227143668370244, 0.00851788756388416,
0.00170357751277683, 0.00056785917092561, 0.0100250626566416,
0.00584795321637427, 0.0133779264214047, 0.000587199060481503,
0.0129183793305931, 0.00176159718144451, 0.000587199060481503,
0.000881834215167548, 0.0167548500881834, 0.00793650793650794,
0.0017636684303351)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your data, but may be due to low n in one of your cells for the 3-way interaction. Take a look at `with(ds1, table(Species,  Habitat, Season))` to get a sense. And are you getting any warnings when you run your ANOVA? If this doesn’t shed any light, please [edit] your post to include your data (run `dput(ds1)`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get this warning when I run an anova to compare the models "Error in if (dispersion == 1) Inf else min(resdf) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". I don't get any warning when I run an anova for just one of the models. Is it of any significance that I don't have the same issue with any other the other models that use the same dataset?